# I want to setup a would you like to retry

Tags: python

I have created a guess the number game, at the end of it I want it to ask the user if they would like to retry. I got it to take invalid responses and if Yes then it will carry on, but when I say no it still carries on.

```
import random
from time import sleep
#Introduction & Instructions
print ("Welcome to guess the number")
print ("A random number from 0 - 1000 will be generated")
print ("And you have to guess it ")
print ("To help find it you can type in a number")
print ("And it will say higher or lower")

guesses = 0
number = random.randint(0, 1)#Deciding the number
while True:   
    guess = int (input("Your guess: "))#Taking the users guess

    #Finding if it is higher, lower or correct
    if guess < number:
        print ("higher")
        guesses += 1

    elif guess > (number):
        print ("lower")
        guesses += 1

    elif guess == (number):
        print ("Correct")
        print (" ")
        print ("It took you {0} tries".format(guesses))

        #Asking if they want another go
        while True:
            answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
                print ('Invalid input.')
            if answer == 'y':
                continue
            if answer == 'n':
                exit()
```

Comment: Your question does not contain a real question. Also it is unclear what you mean by "it will carry on", and in which cases that happens. Do you mean it stays in the loop asking if the user wants to retry, or do you mean it keeps granting retries? Please edit your question to explain your actual question more precisely, and minimize your code to the bare minimum needed for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you check :

```
if answer in ('y','n'):
```

This means that you are checking if `answer` exists in the tuple `('y','n')`.
The desired input is in this tuple, so you may not want to print `Invalid input.` inside this statement.

Also, the break statement in python stops the execution of current loop and takes the control out of it. When you `break`ed the loop inside this statement, the control never went to the printing statement or other `if` statements.

Then you are checking if answer is `'y'` or `'n'`. If it would have been either of these, it would have matched the first statement as explained above.

The code below will work :

```
#Asking if they want another go
while True:
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if answer == 'y':
        break
    elif answer == 'n':
        exit()
    else:
        print ('Invalid input.')
        continue
```

Also, you might want to keep the `number = random.randint(0, 1)#Deciding the number` statement inside the while loop to generate a new random number everytime the user plays the game.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the second while loop in your code. Currently when you put y or n it will break and run again (you don't see the invalid message due to the break occurring before reaching that code), it should be correct if you change it to the following:

```
while True:
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    # if not answer in ('y', 'n'):
    if answer not in ('y', 'n'): # edit from Elis Byberi 
        print('Invalid input.')
        continue
    elif answer == 'y':
        break
    elif answer == 'n':
        exit()
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this but it should be correct. Let me know if you run into a problem with it.

Comment: `if not answer in ('y', 'n'):` will do a double check. It will do: `if not (answer in ('y', 'n')):`  It is more efficient to do: `if answer not in ('y', 'n'):`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it to the more efficient code.